# RCPP and R discrepancy

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm new to C++ programming and apologize if my solution is in plain sight. I am attempting to use RCPP to speed up a slow R function. I think I've narrowed down the issue to a nested for loop. I've simplified the function and provided one R and one RCPP version for comparison. Will someone please explain why my RCPP function yields different results? Thanks!

```
## Data ##

set.seed(666)
input <- rmultinom(10,2,c(.4,.5,.6)) + 1

## R ##

testR <- \(input){
  M1 <- matrix(c(0.5,0.4,0.0,0.3,0.5,0.0,0.2,0.1,1.0),3,3)
  M2 <- matrix(c(0.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.6,0.0,0.25,0.4,1.0),3,3)
  
  Mrows <- nrow(M1)
  tmsteps <- ncol(input)
  N <- nrow(input)
  
  alphas <- NULL; tmp <- NULL; out <- NULL
  for(i in 1:N){
    alphas = c(0,-1e6,-1e6)
    for(j in 1:tmsteps){
      for(k in 1:Mrows){
        tmp[k] = sum(alphas + M1[,k] + M2[k, input[i,j] ])
      }
      alphas <- tmp
    }
    out[i] <- sum(alphas)
  }
  sum(out)
  }

## RCPP ##

cppFunction('double testRCPP(IntegerMatrix input){
    NumericVector v1 = {0.5,0.4,0.0,0.3,0.5,0.0,0.2,0.1,1.0};
    v1.attr("dim") = Dimension(3, 3);
    NumericMatrix M1 = as<NumericMatrix>(v1);
    
    NumericVector v2 = {0.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.6,0.0,0.25,0.4,1.0};
    v2.attr("dim") = Dimension(3, 3);
    NumericMatrix M2 = as<NumericMatrix>(v2);
    
    int Mrows = M1.nrow();
    int tmsteps = input.ncol();
    int N = input.nrow();
    
    NumericVector alphas(3);
    NumericVector tmp(3);
    NumericVector out(N);
    
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    alphas = {0,-1e6,-1e6};
      for(int j=0; j<tmsteps; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<Mrows; k++){
        tmp[k] = sum(alphas + M1(_,k) + M2(k, (input(i,j) - 1) ));
        }
      alphas = tmp;
    }
      out += alphas;
    }
    return(sum(out));
  }')

> testRCPP(input)
[1] -2.273726e+14
> testR(input)
[1] -354293536945
```

Comment: That's fairly far from being a _minimal_ example.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Apologies! Relative to the real function it is. I'll try to whittle it down further.

Comment: in R you have `out[i] <- sum(alphas)` while in c++ you have `out += alphas`. These two statements are different

Comment: @onyambu Good point. Definitely an inefficiency, but it doesn't change the outcome (no need to `sum` out variable if using `+=`). I'll try to simplify my question when I have some time.

Comment: It does change the outcome. Note that alphas is a vector. thus `out += alphas` meas that you have `out[1] + alpha[1], out[2] + alpha[2]` etc but `out[i] = sum(alphas)` means `out[1] = alpha[1] + alpha[2] + alpha[3] + ...` hence the result of out for the two will be different. Simple example. Lets say out  = 1,2,3,4 and alphas = 1,1,1,1 then using `out +=alphas` we end up with `out = 2,3,4,5` but using `out[i] = sum(alphas)` will end up with `out = 6,7,8,9` Note the difference?

Comment: Okay Thanks! I didn't realize c++ was using vectorization. What I want is `out[1] = alpha[1] + ...`. My real code looks like `out[i] = logsumexp(alphas)`, but was trying to simplify since `logsumexp` isn't native to R or c++. I'm also getting the same results with `out[i] = sum(alphas)`

Comment: So did that fix the issue? I hope both cpp and R ARE GIVING YOU THE SAME RESULTS

Comment: That didn't fix the issue unfortunately. I had previously tried it both way and got identical answers which partly led to my misunderstanding of `+=`. I really appreciate the help though!

Comment: I had a suspicion my problem had something to do with variable scope and I have just stumbled on the solution. It has to do with where I declare the `tmp` variable. I still don't quite understand how c++ handles scoping, but at least I can look into it from here. I guess I will answer my own question now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to get the `Rcpp` to behave like the `R` function. I think my issue has to do with `C++` variable scoping.

I had previously been initializing the `tmp` variable outside the nested `for` loop.

```
NumericVector tmp(3);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    alphas = {0,-1e6,-1e6};
    ...
```

All is good when I declare the `tmp` variable inside the loop, although I don't understand why yet.

```
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    alphas = {0,-1e6,-1e6};
      for(int j=0; j<tmsteps; j++){
      NumericVector tmp(3);
        for(int k=0; k<Mrows; k++){
        tmp[k] = sum(alphas + M1(_,k) + M2(k, (input(i,j) - 1) ));
        }
      alphas = tmp;
    }
...
```